# How to use color in legal documents

Tags: print-design, text

Most legal documents like [this](https://www.michalsons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Protection-of-State-Information-Bill-POSIB_bill06D-2010-Michalsons.pdf) are just black and white, with some bold and italic thrown in there, as well as indentation and changes in font size. But you don't really see [color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53930/how-is-color-used-in-document-design) in there. The same with legal forms like [this driver's license form](http://www.bidsync.com/DPXViewer/DL_44_Eng__Pt_1.pdf%3Fac%3Dauction%26auc%3D224148%26rndid%3D442373%26docid%3D1175916). It's just black and white.

I'm wondering what would be a good use of color (and why you would use it) in some legal document like the ones above. Wondering what would justify adding color.

- It just "seems nice". Kind of vague, you can make plain b+w documents look nice too.
- It enhances something. This is kind of vague though, not sure what this would mean.
- Branding. But I don't see how you'd decide what elements would need branding, other than say a single logo in the whole document (so there would only be one tiny piece of color in the document).
- Figures. But you could just do figures in b+w too.
- Etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Spanish Ministry of Finance uses monochrome colored forms + black ink to help the user distinguish them:

[image]

Or colors to differentiate areas to be filled by the user:

[image]

Some examples at Google image search: [Modelo 036](https://www.google.com/search?q=modelo%20036&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj14uvMqbXfAhXlXhUIHSHxDXgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1962&bih=1156), [Modelo 100](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1962&bih=1156&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=eCsfXO2uH_yP1fAPn-OkoAQ&q=modelo%20100&oq=modelo%20100&gs_l=img.3..0l7j0i5i30l3.2082.2171..2588...0.0..0.91.179.2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.FMsdqGxOvf8), [Modelo 130](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1962&bih=1156&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=8ysfXL2xJ_eF1fAP6euskA4&q=modelo%20130&oq=modelo%20130&gs_l=img.3..35i39j0l7j0i5i30l2.2509.2800..2957...0.0..0.85.170.2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.GraOPdXM3rE)

Answer (score 1):

Branding can definitely be a reason if templates have already been designed or instructed for, then color needs to be used.

Another reason is highlighting, in some very complex forms like @Danielillo attached, it helps to break the content into boxes of different color.

Be aware:

- color printing can be more expensive than b&w, and this matters for large print runs
- when printed on b&w hardware, color becomes gray which may be a problem as you'll be losing contrast